# ¿Cómo poner video que se reproduzca solo?

Tags: html, html5

Quiero poner video automático, pero no me va, estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
<video width="600" height="400" autoplay>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: ¿En qué navegador has probado?

Comment: ¿Te aparece algún error en la consola del navegador?

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="600" height="400" autoplay>
```

Reelmplazalo por

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" **preload="auto"** width="450" controls="controls">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

o agregale solo **preload="auto"**

Comment: Consideren que el autoplay por más que lo ponga, en la mayoría de ocasiones no funcionará. Esto es porque los navegadores lo consideran una practica que van a en contra de la experiencia de usuario y lo restringen, sin embargo tiene más probabilidad que el autoplay funcione, si  silencia el video.